# Go 1.18 migration issues — Cannot convert 'nil' to type 'any'

Tags: go, generics, ide, goland

I updated my codebase to Go 1.18. It all looks great, but in a few places, I found the following issues.

```
defer func() {
    if e := recover() ; e!=nil {
        ...
    }
}()
```

Compilation is failing with:

> Cannot convert 'nil' to type 'any'

The same code was working good with Go 1.17. Based on Go 1.18 Release notes, `any` is a built-in type of alias for `interface{}` (Generics)

What is going on?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The issue is with the IDE. IntelliJ Goland 2021.2.4

I can build the code from the command line and in the [playground](https://go.dev/play/p/kVijGgqgN9I).

Comment: Is there a fix/update for the IDE? Or a `gopls` update perhaps?

Comment: Yes, the fix is included in the newer versions of GoLand, e.g. 2021.3.4 or the [EAP build](https://www.jetbrains.com/go/nextversion/).